# c standard library sort function from programming pearls

Tags: c

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>



int intcomp(int *x,int *y) {  return *x-*y;};
int a[10000];
int main(void){
    int i; int n=0;
     while (scanf("%d",&a[n])!=EOF)
          n++;
     qsort(a,n,sizeof(int),intcomp);
      for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
           printf("%d\n",a[i]);
       return 0;


}
```

it is just copy of code  i have two question it show  me that intcomp is incompatible  in this code
 and also   what does intcomp function?
and also what is in windows 7 EOF?  how tell program that it reached EOF?

Comment: The code breaks as soon as the 10001st number is entered.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++ when it's obviously C ?

Comment: Now it is tagged C while the accepted answer suggests to use a C++ based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: the question is labeled C++ and you #include <algorithm> and <iostream>, but your code is 100% C.

Martin York already gave the answer how to correct the signature of the function you pass to qsort().

However, the "true"(TM) C++ solution would be to use std::sort<> instead of qsort!

```
#include <algorithm>    
#include <stdio.h>    

bool intcomp(int a, int b) { return a<b; }
int a[10000];    
int main(void){    
    int n=0;    
     while (scanf("%d",&a[n])!=EOF)    
          n++;    
     std::sort(&a[0], &a[n], intcomp);
      for (int i=0;i<n;i++)    
           printf("%d\n",a[i]);    
       return 0;    
}
```

Note that incomp() takes ints and not int pointers, and returns a bool. Just like operator<() would.

Also note that in this case, you could forget the intcomp and just use std::sort(&a[0], &a[n]), which will use std::less<>, which will use operator<(int, int).

Answer (score 4):

the qsort() function requires a pointer with a particular signature.
Your function has the wrong signature so it is complaining.

Your function has the signature:

```
int intcomp(int *x,int *y)
```

While qsort requires the signature:

```
int intcomp(void const* xp,void const* yp)
```

Please note the difference in the parameter types.

A corrected version of the function is:

```
int intcomp(void const* xp,void const* yp)
{
  // Modified for C as the tag on the question changed:
  // int x = *static_cast<int const*>(xp);
  // int y = *static_cast<int const*>(yp);
  int x = *((int const*)(xp));
  int y = *((int const*)(yp));

  return x-y;
}
```

The function qsort() is passed a function pointer as the third parameter.
This function pointer (in your case intcomp()) is used to compare values in the array passed. Each call provides pointers into the array. The result of the function should be:

```
Less than 0:    if x is smaller than y
0:              If x is equal to y
Greater than 0: If x is larger than y
```

Comment: You need to amend your type casts in `intcomp` to be C style because the question is no longer C++. i.e. `int x = *(int*)xp;`

Comment: @JeremyP: Will do. But when I answered the tag was C++

Comment: York:  Yes, I know.  My comment wasn't intended as criticism, just trying to make you aware the tag had changed.

Answer (score 1):

`intcomp` is an "Int Compare" function. It is passed a pointer to 2 ints and returns 0 if they are the same, a positive value is x > y and a negative value is x < y.

`qsort` is passed a pointer to this function and calls it each time it wants to know how to sort a pair of values.

The docs for `qsort` should give you some more details.
eg http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/other/qsort

Comment: Actually `intcomp` is broken because it has overflow cases. (What happens if `x` is `INT_MIN` and `y` is `INT_MAX`? :) It should be modified to use conditionals or some fancy tricks with unsigned arithmetic or larger types to avoid overflow issues.

Answer (score 1):

`qsort` is in `stdlib.h`, so include that file at the beginning. Note that `algorithm` and `iostream` aren't needed.

`#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: By the way, the std::sort algorithm would be much more in C++ style.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin York mentioned, qsort needs a function which it will use to compare the values:

```
void qsort( void *buf, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compare)(const void*, const void *) );
```

Here is a good example on how to use qsort: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/other/qsort

Edit: Ri was faster....